# How can I include an existing custom sitemaps listing in wp-sitemap.xml?

Tags: filters, sitemap

I have several existing custom sitemap xml files, and I'd like to know which add_filter to use to add those custom sitemaps to the existing https://www.example.com/wp-sitemap.xml page.

Answer (score 0):

[There are a lot to choose from.](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=sitemap&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook)

I would start with [`wp_sitemap_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_sitemaps_init/), whose documentation states

> Additional sitemaps should be registered on this hook.

Note that you'll have to be running WordPress 5.5.0 or up for this hook to be available.

Looking at [the code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.6/src/wp-includes/sitemaps.php#L13), it appears that this action allows you to register new items in the global `$wp_sitemaps` object, which is a [`WP_Sitemaps`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_sitemaps/) object.

Comment: Thank you.  I have definitely seen the links you provided, and have seen several examples of registering a new sitemap provider, etc. but they all seem overkill if all I'm wanting to do is add a couple of sitemap xml file links inside the existing default wp-sitemaps.xml file.  Any insight on a simpler approach is much appreciated.

Comment: I did a bunch of work on a Multisite sitemap for my employer's website, but it appears I ignored all the filters (or—since it was a while ago—some of the filters might not have existed yet) and basically wrote something up from essentially scratch.